# Unknown glyph symbols on the Volume Mixer

Tags: windows-7, volume-mixer

I get these symbols on the volume mixer. It seems to happen at the end of every line. This is a nearly clean install of Windows 7 x64 (only Chrome and Firefox installed).

Any idea where this could be coming from? The system is using all the default fonts.

It is not a localization issue, and has since happened again on a completely clean install of Windows 7 x64 Ultimate (no 3rd party apps).

It almost appears as though the UI is attempting to render newline characters.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I have this too (right now in fact). I also think I've seen it come and go when I did something particular, like launch a specific program or such. I'll keep an eye out.

Comment: How do you define 'nearly clean'? I see firefox and chrome on your screenshot, what other software did you install?

Comment: It seems like an error in your installation, since this is a new installation, I would recommend you to check for the correct graphics driver. If you have the correct (and up to date) graphics driver installed, I would try to reinstall win7.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After reading [this article](http://www.sevenforums.com/sound-audio/135165-weird-text-glitch-volume-mixer-2.html), I would suggest deleting `FNTCACHE.DAT` in C:\Windows\System32 as suggested by anoise:

> I re-installed Windows 7 and the squares where there again, BUT I got rid of them now. It seems the solution, for me anyway, was to delete the file FNTCACHE.DAT in Windows\System32 and restart. 
>   I tried this before re-installing windows 7 but it did not work, this time however it worked. For two weeks now I'm free of the squares and Chinese characters are displayed correctly too in explorer.
>   Yes it seems the problem with Chinese characters displayed as squares in explorer and the squares in mixer volume are going hand in hand and is a bug in windows 7 font cache or something...

Answer (score 1):

This is because of your localization settings, as buttertoad mentioned.

My windows was by default `English - South Africa` I then changed it to `English - Trinidad` and it broke my Volume Mixer as you experience it.

To fix it, I changed my settings back to `English - South Africa`, I went a step further and removed all other keyboard languages.

Note: You have to restart after changing your localization settings.

`Control Panel - Region and Language Settings`

[image: Screen shot with before (error) and after (fixed) as well extra snippets]

Answer (score 0):

Check your language settings. When I've seen similar issues it's been because of an unsupported language or localization setting.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have these squares under Windows 7 running IE8. I did have the squares when running the same laptop with IE9.
Also I have a brand new Windows 8 machine, that comes default with IE10 - the squares are also present, with minimal programs installed.

So the problem must be related to Internet Explorer versions 9 and 10 - the University computers (at the university I go to) have Windows 7 Enterprise and IE10 - squares present.

I tried the font cache on my windows 7 Home Premium laptop and this done absolutely nothing.

Solution: If you have Windows 7, roll back to IE8 and use Chrome or Firefox as your default browser. I don't know about windows 8, since you cannot uninstall IE10...