# Why are these boxes next to my sound devices?

Tags: sound-card

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unknown glyph symbols on the Volume Mixer](https://superuser.com/questions/372082/unknown-glyph-symbols-on-the-volume-mixer)

After I reformatted my computer and installed all of the drivers, the applications making sound in sound manager have boxes next to them. This worries me as I believe it may be a wrong driver possibly? Here is a picture of it. What would cause this? How can I fix it?

[image: Boxes]

Updates:
It is windows 7 Home Premium. Sound functions fine.

Comment: More info on the operating system and hardware would help but this appears normal.  Does sound function?

Comment: I'm seeing these on Windows 7 Professional (assuming that's what you are using) here at work and at home now you come to mention it.

Comment: I added the OS and the sound does work.

Comment: Looks like a GUI/Graphics glitch rather than an actual problem. If it works fine don't worry, they'll probably go with a Windows Update/Driver update/Service Pack at some point.