# Why is windows 8 rendering CRLFs as a Square Character

Tags: language, windows-8, charset

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unknown glyph symbols on the Volume Mixer](https://superuser.com/questions/372082/unknown-glyph-symbols-on-the-volume-mixer)

In a number of random locations in windows 8 (one of which is the volume control) it seems to be rendering the end of line as a visible square character. Anyone got any idea what this might be. I've tried flipping the Language prefs back to en-Us but to no avail.

[image: Windows 8 Square Characters]

Comment: I checked on my Win 8 Enterprise trial and I have the same thing.

Comment: ok. some maybe a genuine bug. I've seen it in other places as well, (visual studio, office) in Win8 Pro (non trial).

Answer (score 4):

If you delete C:\Windows\System32\FNTCACHE.DAT and reboot, it will be fixed.  I had this same problem and this worked for me.