# Why are there squares showing in window titles?

Tags: windows-8, fonts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unknown glyph symbols on the Volume Mixer](https://superuser.com/questions/372082/unknown-glyph-symbols-on-the-volume-mixer)

I've come across an issue that has me totally stumped. I am finding squares in my window titles in various programs around Windows 8. I know these "squares" are typically non-printable characters, but I don't know why they would be showing up in system areas. I am running Windows 8 Enterprise, and I installed it last week. The *only* modifications I've made to the registry were making the window borders more narrow.

For example, a pop-up message from Visual Studio (The VS theme I use makes this title hard to see):
[image: Visual Studio square in title]

And the Win8 volume mixer:

[image: Volume mixer, squares in device names]

Any ideas on what I might have done to cause this?